# Why is form body returning null on PUT request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Why is the form data not being stored in req.body?

EJS/HTML

```
<form onsubmit="EditJob()" class="editForm">
      <div class="form-group-edit">
        <label for="position">Position</label>
        <input type="position" id="position" name="position" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Position Title"
        />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group-edit">
        <label for="company">Company</label>
        <input type="company" id="company" name="company" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Company Name"
        />
      </div>

      <button type="submit" class="edit">
        <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
      </button>
    </form>
```

Client JS

```
const EditJob = () => {
  const id = ####;
  const url = `http://localhost:5000/dashboard/${id}`;
  axios.put(url).then(res => {
    console.log(res);
  });
};
```

Server JS

```
router.put("/:id", (req, res) => {
  Job.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {
    position: req.body.position,
    company: req.body.company,
    status: req.body.status
  })
...
...
});
```

Updated doc in my database results in {position: null, company: null, status: null}..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you're using `body-parser`, or **set your express middleware** like code below:

```js
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
```

⚠️ When you're using `axios.put()`, make sure you passing your `data` in there. You can read the documentation [here](https://github.com/axios/axios)

**An Example: Axios Put**

```js
axios.put(endPoint, data, config).then(...).catch(...)
```

I hope it's can help you.

Comment: The issue for the OP is the second thing.  You must send data with `axios.put()`.